# Sending email to several recipients via nodemailer doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I tried looking for different answers but they didn't work. I don't receive the email in my gmail account when I am trying to send it, I am just getting it in my Ethereal account.

This is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cons = require('consolidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();

app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('../public', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.use('../src/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/css')));
app.use('../src/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/js')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/send',(req,res) => {
    const output = `
        <p>name of client: ${req.body.name}</p>
    `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
        user: "*****@ethereal.email",
        pass: "********"
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: `${req.body.email}`,
        to: "******@gmail.com",
        subject: "Node contact request",
        text: "Hello world?",
        html: output
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
        console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        res.render('index')
    });
});

app.listen(5000);
```

I am using react app for my front-end(e-commerce), and I want that after sending the email the client will see a message saying "The email has been sent" (the location doesn't really matter for now). How can I do it after submitting the form? Right now the client is directing to localhost:5000/send instead of staying at the same page.

This is my react code:

```
import React from 'react';

const contact = () => {
    return (
    <form className="contact" action="http://localhost:5000/send" method="post">
        <div className="contact-topFields">
            <div className="contact-topFields-email">
                <input 
                    className="contact-topFields-email-input" 
                    type="email" 
                    name="email" 
                    required/>
                <ion-icon id="email-icon" name="mail"></ion-icon>
                <p className="contact-topFields-email-text">Email</p>
            </div>
            <div className="contact-topFields-name">
                <input 
                    className="contact-topFields-name-input" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="name" 
                    required/>
                <ion-icon id="name-icon" name="person"></ion-icon>
                <p className="contact-topFields-name-text">Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="contact-bottomFields">
            <div className="contact-bottomFields-phone">
                <input 
                    className="contact-bottomFields-phone-input" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="phonenumber" 
                    required/>
                <ion-icon id="phone-icon" name="call"></ion-icon>
                <p className="contact-topFields-phone-text">phone</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="contact-text">
            <textarea className="contact-text-textarea" name="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button className="contact-submitButton" type="submit">send </button>
    </form>

    )
}

export default contact;
```

Comment: Are you asking two questions here? One is the email failed to be sent. The other one is, UI was directed to another page instead of staying at the previous one after submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, but the first one is more important @nick

Comment: What was returned from console.log?

Comment: Message sent: <19f08c3d-efef-f87b-2d77-822b42a14b0e@gmail.com>
Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/XHXds4BQ8BiiM19yXHYB4ORxKgyy8A0qAAAADLkETe9u0IcgQaVYm6Ja4MY

Comment: did you receive the email after that? I can't see any problem here. If you didn't receive the email, then you may want to log into email service provider's wizard to take a look.

Answer (score -1):

**To prevent the page being directed to localhost:5000/send:**

In order to trigger sending the email while keep the user's view unchanged, you may want to override the form's submit function.

For example, you may want to do this in your JSX code:

```
<form className="contact" onSubmit={{this.handleSubmit}}>
<- whatever inside form ->
</form>
```

Then you may want to define a function `handleSubmit`:

```
function handleSubmit (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault() // this is used to prevent ui from being directed

  // Do http request here, use a http agent such as fetch(), axios() etc etc. 

}
```